# Как сделать скрипт отправки сообщения с сайта на E-Mail?

Tags: php

Как сделать скрипт отправки сообщения с сайта на E-Mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
function get_data($smtp_conn)
{
    $data="";
    while($str = fgets($smtp_conn,515))
    {
        $data .= $str;
        if(substr($str,3,1) == " ") { break; }
    }
    return $data;
}
function SendMail($config)
{
if(!isset($config['priority']))
  $config['priority']=3;

$header="Date: ".date("D, j M Y G:i:s")." +0700\r\n";
$header.="From: =?windows-1251?Q?".str_replace("+","_",str_replace("%","=",urlencode("{$config['from_title']}")))."?= <{$config['from']}>\r\n";
$header.="X-Mailer: The Bat! (v3.99.3) Professional\r\n";
$header.="Reply-To: =?windows-1251?Q?".str_replace("+","_",str_replace("%","=",urlencode("{$config['from_title']}")))."?= <{$config['from']}>\r\n";
$header.="X-Priority: {$config['priority']}\r\n";
$header.="Message-ID: <172562218.".date("YmjHis")."@microsoft.com>\r\n";
$header.="To: =?windows-1251?Q?".str_replace("+","_",str_replace("%","=",urlencode($config['to_title'])))."?= <{$config['to']}>\r\n";
$header.="Subject: =?windows-1251?Q?".str_replace("+","_",str_replace("%","=",urlencode($config['subject'])))."?=\r\n";
$header.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header.="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"----------A4D921C2D10D7DB\"\r\n";

$attach=NULL;
$code_file=NULL;
if(isset($config['attach_file']))
{  
 if(file_exists($config['attach_file']))
 {
  $fp = fopen($config['attach_file'], "rb");
  $code_file = chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($fp, filesize($config['attach_file']))));
  fclose($fp);
  $attach.="------------A4D921C2D10D7DB
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($config['attach_file'])."\"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($config['attach_file'])."\"

{$code_file}";
 }
}

if(isset($config['attach_dir']))
{
  $dir = $config['attach_dir']; 
  if (is_dir($dir))      
   if ($dh = opendir($dir)) 
   { 
     while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) 
       if($file!="." && $file!="..")
       {
           $fp = fopen($dir.$file, "rb");
  $code_file = chunk_split(base64_encode(fread($fp, filesize($dir.$file))));
  fclose($fp);
  $attach.="------------A4D921C2D10D7DB
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($dir.$file)."\"
Content-transfer-encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($dir.$file)."\"

{$code_file}";

       }
     closedir($dh); 
   } 

}

if(isset($config['html_file']))
{
  if(file_exists($config['html_file']))
  {
    $filename = $config['html_file'];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    $config['html'].=$contents;
  }
}

$text="------------A4D921C2D10D7DB
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

{$config['html']}

{$attach}\r\n


------------A4D921C2D10D7DB--
";

$smtp_conn = fsockopen($config['server'], $config['port'],$errno, $errstr, 10);
if(!$smtp_conn) {print "Connect is fail"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}
$data = get_data($smtp_conn);
fputs($smtp_conn,"EHLO ".time()."\r\n");
$code = substr(get_data($smtp_conn),0,3);
if($code != 250) {print "Command fail EHLO"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}

if(isset($config['login']))
{
  fputs($smtp_conn,"AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
  $code = substr(get_data($smtp_conn),0,3);
  if($code != 334) {print "Command fail AUTH LOGIN"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}

  fputs($smtp_conn,base64_encode($config['login'])."\r\n");
  $code = substr(get_data($smtp_conn),0,3);
  if($code != 334) {print "Login is not exists"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}

  fputs($smtp_conn,base64_encode($config['password'])."\r\n");
  $code = substr(get_data($smtp_conn),0,3);
  if($code != 235) {print "Password is not correct"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}
}

$size_msg=strlen($header."\r\n".$text);

fputs($smtp_conn,"MAIL FROM:<{$config['from']}> SIZE=".$size_msg."\r\n");

$code = substr(get_data($smtp_conn),0,3);
if($code != 250) {print "Command fail MAIL FROM"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}

fputs($smtp_conn,"RCPT TO:<{$config['to']}>\r\n");
$code = substr(get_data($smtp_conn),0,3);
if($code != 250 AND $code != 251) {print "Command fail RCPT TO"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}

fputs($smtp_conn,"DATA\r\n");
$code = substr(get_data($smtp_conn),0,3);
if($code != 354) {print "Command fail DATA"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}

fputs($smtp_conn,$header."\r\n".$text."\r\n.\r\n");
$code = substr(get_data($smtp_conn),0,3);
if($code != 250) {print "Send main error"; fclose($smtp_conn); exit;}

fputs($smtp_conn,"QUIT\r\n");
fclose($smtp_conn);

if(@$config['debug']=="on")
{
  echo "<pre><code>";
  print_r($config);
  echo "</code></pre>";

  echo "Attach file:<br>{$attach}";
}
else
 echo "200: OK";
}
/*
server - smtp.mail.ru
port - 25

login - barsukov.vv@mail.ru
passowrd - *********

from - admin@yandex.ru
from_title - Администрация Яндекс.ру

to - target@domain.net
to_title - Target

subject - Spam
html - <div style='font-size:36pt;'>html</div>
html_file - html/plain.html

priority : важность
      1 - высокая
      3 - обычная(по умолчанию)
      5 - низкая

attach_file - image.jpg
attach_dir - image/

debug - De`жук(on)
*/
SendMail(array("from"=>"admin@yandex.ru", "from_title"=>"Администрация Yandex.ru", "to"=>"barsukov.vv@mail.ru", "to_title"=>"Барсуков Владимир", "server"=>"mail-omsk.omsk.srsh.ru", "port"=>25, "subject"=>time(), "html"=>"html", "attach_file"=>"test/mazda.jpg", "attach_dir"=>"test/", "html_file"=>"test.html", "priority"=>"1", "debug"=>"on"));
?>
```

Вот самописный расширенная отправка письма

Answer (score 4):

[Отправка почты средствами PHP](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mail#part_1).

```
<?php 
    mail("to@somewhere.ru", "Subject", "message"); 
?>
```